# document.body is null in cordova in meteor 1.3

Tags: cordova, meteor

I've been trying to append some contents in body tag from javascript.

https://github.com/aruntk/meteor-cordova-body-test/blob/master/client/main.js#L23

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1 style='color:green'>Success</h1>"
```

Its working fine in web browsers. But when I tried to run the same code in an android device I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of 'null'

I've tried to add this in a timeout function and it did work. But I dont see anything wrong with the first method. Is there something that I'm missing? And if there is an issue why is it working as expected in browsers?

Here is the sample repo. https://github.com/aruntk/meteor-cordova-body-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by running the code in the deviceready event listener callback.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); 

function onDeviceReady(){
        document.body.innerHTML += "<h1 style='color:green'>Success</h1>"
}
```